# can't get connection with sqlite DB

Tags: php, sqlite

I am quite familiar with PHP and mySQL. But for a change, I wanted to use sqlite as a DB, I just can't get the connection right. I have been following the 2. code example from [this](http://php.net/manual/de/pdo.construct.php) website, so my code looks like this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>
        DB bearbeiten
    </title>
</head>
<body>

    <form action="insert.php" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name">
        <input type="text" name="eName" placeholder="E-Number">
        <input type="text" name="causes" placeholder="Wirkung">
        <input type="number" name="danger" placeholder="Gefahreinstufung">
        <button type="submit" name="submit">Eintragen</button>
    </form>

    <?php
    echo '1';
        if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
            echo '2';
            $table = "zusatzstoffe";
            $filename = "sqlite:/data/Adrian/zusatzstoffe.db";
            $db = new PDO($filename) or die("cannot open DB");

            //$db = SQLite3::_construct();
            settype($danger, "integer");
            $name = $_POST['name'];
            $eName = $_POST['eName'];
            $causes = $_POST['causes'];
            $danger = $_POST['danger'];
            $db->exec("INSERT INTO $table (name, number, causes, danger) VALUES ($name, $eName, $causes, $danger)");
        }

    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

This line doesn't work, I just don't know why: `$db = new PDO(filename, '','') or die("can not open DB");`:

Comment: That should probably be `$filename = "sqlite:/data/Adrian/zusatzstoffe.db;`, and you don't need the second and third argument when initialising the PDO object - just `new PDO($filename)` is enough.

Comment: Thanks, although it resolves on problem another occured. Sadly i can't get the Error log, because the server restricts it working on it though.

Comment: Probably because you're not enclosing the values in the last line with `'` (`'$name', '$number' ... )`. Although I'd advise you to not use `exec()` but rather prepared statements, for security reasons.

Comment: Indeed use a prepared statement `$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO $table (name, number, causes, danger) VALUES (?,?,?,?)"); $stmt->execute(array($name, $eName, $causes, $danger));`